# UICollectionViewのセルの移動

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

コレクションビューのセルをドラッグで移動させたいです。
テーブルビューの場合は、編集モードで行の移動が出来ると思いますが、コレクションビューにはそういった機能はあるのでしょうか？

UICollectionViewDataSourceプロトコルに

```
・public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,canMoveItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
・public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

また、UICollectionViewに

```
・public func moveItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath newIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

といったメソッドがあるようなのですが、これらメソッドを使用してセルの移動が出来るのでしょうか？

お知恵をお貸しいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

こちらのサイトが参考になるのではないでしょうか。
[UICollectionViews Now Have Easy Reordering](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/)

英語のサイトですが、GitHubからサンプルプロジェクトも落とせますし、実際に動くコードを見ながら読めばざっくりと方法はわかると思います。

(1) `UICollectionViewController`を使う場合
基本的に`collectionView(_:moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:)`を実装するだけ。

(2) 自前のViewControllerを使う場合
上記の他、GestureRecoginizerを使って、(移動のための)dragの開始/状態変化/終了処理を書いてやる必要がある。

(3) 自前のViewControllerでさらにカスタムlayoutを使う場合
上記の他、自前のLayoutクラスでいくつかのメソッドをoverrideしてやる。

注意点としては、iOS9以降の機能ですので、開発中のアプリをiOS9以降のみの対応にして良いかどうかは要チェックです。問題ないのであれば、サンプルコードを試して見られると良いかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！まさに貼って頂いたサイトに書かれているようなことがやりたかったので、参考にしながら試行錯誤してみます。感謝いたします。